# Magento 2: Class 'ObjectManager' not found

Tags: magento2, object-manager

I have a cron to launch to erase a database table,
here is the cron

```
<?php
    require_once 'Controller/Adminhtml/NewProduct.php';
    $cron=new \Managys\Pricing\Controller\Adminhtml\NewProduct();
    $cronGo = $cron->GetNewproduct();
?>
```

Class New Product:

```
class NewProduct
{
public function GetNewproduct(){
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('mp_new_products');
....}
```

in order to call this cron I have an error
[image]

Comment: where I put it under the module always same error

Comment: yes this module is working properly

Comment: okay post the whole file code here for better idea - Also after that have you compile the code - by running command setup:di:compile ?

Comment: I ran the command php bin / magento setup: di: compile; but no change.

Comment: for my code here I changed the file location here I have two part initila cron and class New product.

Comment: here is the cron
<?php
        require_once 'Price.php';
        $cron=new \Managys\Pricing\Price();
        $cronGo = $cron->GetNewproduct();
?>

Comment: Price.php  here I put everything else in comment
<?php
namespace Managys\Pricing;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
class Price

{


    function GetNewproduct()
    {
        $objectManager = ObjectManager::getInstance();
//        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
//        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
//        $tableName = $resource->getTableName('mp_new_products');
    }
}